# What does "take a drop" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "take a drop" mean? It's from The Invisible Man

> Where'd you be, if he **took a drop** over and above, and had a fancy to go for you?

Comment: Hmm can you add more context for those of us that haven't seen/read what you're referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to "take a drop" in this context means "to drink some alcohol", and quite possibly "to drink too much alcohol".

It was always more common in the UK than in the US, and I think it is now rather old fashioned.

Comment: _Over and above_ does imply 'too much' - possibly making the man aggressive and likely to 'go for' the person addressed.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Quite true, but I think even just "He took a drop last night" is sometimes used to imply "he drank too much".